# File Transfer mode in sftp

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

I am a newbie to `ftp` and `sftp` as well as Linux. Can you please advise what is the default mode of file transfer in `sftp`? I know in `ftp`, we have transfer modes (binary and ascii).

It would also be great if you can provide any link or document which can provide me clear understanding of SCP, SSH and SFTP.

*P.S. I have been suggested to move here from stackoverflow getting -1 point there.*

Comment: They asked to move here? !!

Comment: looked up into en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol , but couldn't find anything for file transfer mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.weonlydo.com/SFTPdll/Help/wodSFTPLib~wodSFTP~TransferMode.html : "the sftp protocol does not distinguish between binary and ascii transfer modes".  Presumably the Wikipedia pages are a good starting point for finding out more about these topics.